# Origins of formula of finding area inside a symmetrical curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let's say I have a symmetrical curve $C$, and I want to find area $A$ inside it. I found, that I need to use this formula:

$A=4\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left(x(t)y'(t)-y(t)x'(t)\right)\ dt}.$

It's more or less understandable why there are exactly such boundaries of integration, and the integral itself is multiplied by 4. But I do not understand where the integrand itself came from, could someone explain, please?

Comment: It’s a bit easier to understand if you move the $\frac12$ into the integral. Think about how you might approximate the actual area “swept out” by a radial vector from $t$ to $t+\Delta t$ with a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula is specific to a particular parameterization and type of symmetry. Based on the specific numbers here, I'd guess that $t$ is an angular parameter and that the curve has some $4$-fold symmetry.

This sort of formula arises from [writing the area as a line integral $\oint_C (P \,dx + Q \,dy)$ (for suitable $P, Q)$ using Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_calculation), choosing a parameterization of $C$, and expressing the value of that integral as the integral of a usual ($1$-variable) integral.